# How to create a longer \swarrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

When I want to explain something below an equal sign, I use the following syntax:

```
\underset{\big\downarrow}{=}
```

But the position of the elements in one of the expressions I am typing make it impossible for the arrow to go straight down, so I would like to use `\swarrow` instead of `\downarrow`, in the following way:

```
\underset{\big\swarrow}{=}
```

However, to my surprise, this produces an error. Apparently, `\big` does not work with `\swarrow`. Is there anything I can do to produce a longer `\swarrow`?

Edit: This is a minimal compilable example that shows why I need a longer arrow. It is exactly what I am trying to write.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\par\hspace*{8.9cm}\footnotesize equivalentemente,\vspace*{-1.5mm}
\par\hspace*{8.9cm}por componentes\normalsize\vspace*{-12mm}
\[dW=F_xdx+F_ydy+F_zdz=-dU\hspace*{2mm}\Rightarrow\hspace*{2mm}\underset{\swarrow}{\vec{F}}=-\hspace*{-12mm}\underset{\text{de la energí­a magnética}}{\underset{\text{gradiente a flujo constante}}{\underbrace{\nabla U|_\phi}}}\hspace*{-9mm}\overset{\hspace*{-1mm}\big\uparrow}{\Rightarrow}\hspace*{3mm}\begin{cases}F_x=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}\vspace*{2.5mm} \\ F_y=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial y}\vspace*{2.5mm} \\ F_z=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial z}\end{cases}\]
```

I know there is probably a most effective way to produce some of this, using Tikz, but it seemed complicated to me.

Comment: Could you please provide us with a complete compilable example? It might well be that there is a more elegant way than the one you are thinking of.

Comment: @marmot Sorry, I just edited my question and added the example.

Comment: `\big` & Co. act on _delimiters_ like parentheses, brackets, braces and (maybe a bit surprisingly) `\downarrow`. However, `\swarrow` isn't a delimiter. Of course this doesn't answer the question (hence a comment) but I just wanted to shed some light on this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal without any `\hspace` or `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\begin{document}
\[\mathrm{d}W=F_x\,\mathrm{d}x+F_y\,\mathrm{d}y+F_z\,\mathrm{d}z=-\mathrm{d}U
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\tikzmarknode{F}{\vec{F}}=-\tikzmarknode{U}{\nabla U|_\phi}
\quad\tikzmarknode{ar}{\Rightarrow}\quad
\begin{cases}F_x=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x} \\[2.5mm] 
F_y=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial y} \\[2.5mm] 
F_z=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial z}\end{cases}\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[below=3mm of U,anchor=80,font=\scriptsize,align=left] (l1){%
gradiente a flujo constante\\ 
de la energ\'{i}­a magn\'etica};
\draw[-latex] (F.south) -- (l1.160);
\draw[-latex] (U.south) -- (l1);
\node[above=4.5mm of ar,anchor=-40,font=\scriptsize,align=left] (l2){%
equivalentemente,\\ 
por componentes};
\draw[-latex] ([yshift=1.5pt]ar.135) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is really good. Tikz seems wonderful but complicated, anyway this solves my problem, but I'd still need to look into it a bit more to understand the syntax. But apart from this, do you think there could be some way to rotate an arrow as if it were a picture, without using Tikz? With some type of box command, maybe? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @WildFeather Of course, the `graphicx` package comes with the `\rotatebox` command, `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<stuff>}`, see the package documentation for further details.