# lengthening down left arrow- swarrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows, tikz-arrows

My question is related to [How to create a longer \swarrow - TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458860/how-to-create-a-longer-swarrow), however I could not apply the answer to my case.

I want to create a long \swarrow between two objects that appear in different rows. More precisely, this is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \[0\to \underbrace{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}_{\text{black}}\rtimes G\to A\rtimes G\to \frac{A}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}\rtimes G\to 0\]
    $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \swarrow$
    \[0\to \underbrace{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{4}\cap_{i\neq j}A_{g_i}}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}}_{\text{dark gray}}\rtimes G\to \frac{A}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}\rtimes G\to \frac{A}{\sum_{j=1}^{4}\cap_{i\neq j}A_{g_i}}\rtimes G\to 0\]
    
\end{document}
```

I wanted to create an arrow between the last object appears before the zero in the first row, and the middle object appears in the second row (to catch the attention that they are exactly the same object).

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `\ \ \ \ \ \ ...` you can use `\hspace{<length>}`, like `\hspace{7.5cm}`.

Comment: You should probably have a look at the `tikz-cd` package. BTW: don't use `\text` like that. `\text` does not do what you think. In this case `\mathrm` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestion of the users @Phelype Oleinik and @daleif, I have done the code with `tikz-cd` hoping that this answer corresponds to your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.5pt]
0 \arrow[r] & \underbrace{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}_{\mathrm{black}}\rtimes G \arrow[r]                                                 & A\rtimes G \arrow[r] & \frac{A}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}\rtimes G \arrow[r] \arrow[ld]   & 0 \\
0 \arrow[r] & \underbrace{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{4}\cap_{i\neq j}A_{g_i}}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}}_{\mathrm{dark gray}}\rtimes G \arrow[r] & \frac{A}{\cap_{i=1}^{4} A_{g_i}}\rtimes G \arrow[r] & \frac{A}{\sum_{j=1}^{4}\cap_{i\neq j}A_{g_i}}\rtimes G \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```